# what is the benefit of having an object of interface itself declare inside the interface for kotlin

Tags: oop, kotlin, interface

for example

An interface of

```
interface StateInterface {

    val variationTypes: List<VariationType>
        get() = emptyList()

    object EMPTY : StateInterface
}
```

then its been declared inside an actionbean like this

`open val stateInterface: StateInterface = StateInterface.EMPTY`

Is it all it does it just create a new interface? Why we need to do it this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to do it that way.

```
interface StateInterface {

    val variationTypes: List<VariationType>
        get() = emptyList()

}

object EMPTY : StateInterface
```

Would work fine, but the author decided that they wanted the usage to read `StateInterface.EMPTY` and not just `EMPTY`.

One advantage or reason for choosing this way is that `EMPTY` appears in the code completion after typing `StateInterface.` making it easier to find.

[image: Code Completion]

Another readability advantage is that anyone who references `StateInterface.EMPTY` does not need an additional `import` line which they would if it wasn't a nested object.

```
import com.example.StateInterface

val x = StateInterface.EMPTY
```

This bit `open val stateInterface: StateInterface = StateInterface.EMPTY` is a property on an object. It's `open` so descendant implementations can `override` it. If they do not, `StateInterface.EMPTY` will be the value of this property.

Comment: And perhaps a third advantage is that you can have another interface with its own EMPTY member, without a clash of names.